# Issue creating a json object from a variable using simdjson c++ library

Tags: c++, json

I am trying to create a [`simdjson`](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson) object from a variable using the following code. Compiler is complaining about `cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'simdjson::dom::object'`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <simdjson.h>

int main() {
    long idValue = 1234567890;      
    simdjson::dom::element json = simdjson::dom::object("id", idValue);

    std::cout << json << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to create a json object using `idValue`?